# How to change text style into vba foreach loop

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have this regex code and it´s working fine, but I´m trying to manipulate the text inside foreach but is taking no effect at the document.
I want to change the style of the selection and cut the markup off.

```
Sub Substituir()

Set documento = ActiveDocument.Range

Dim texto As String

Set oRegExp = New RegExp
oRegExp.Pattern = "<h1>[\s\S]*?</h1>"
oRegExp.Global = True
oRegExp.MultiLine = True

Dim resultado As MatchCollection

Set resultado = oRegExp.Execute(documento)

For Each r In resultado    
    r.Find.Execute FindText:="<h1>", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    r.Find.Execute FindText:="</h1>", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Next

End Sub
```

The result I´m want is to replace

```
<h1>bla bla</h1>
```

with

```
bla bla
```

And than change the style to Heading 1 in word.

Comment: Do you want to replace `<h1>bla bla bla</h1>` with `bla bla bla` only?

Comment: Try `oRegExp.Pattern = "<h1>([\s\S]*?)</h1>"` and then replace the matching code with `documento.Text = oRegExp.Replace(documento.Text, "$1")`

Comment: Yes I need to replace <h1>bla bla bla</h1> with bla bla bla and turn the selection to bold, or italic for example. The best would be to change it´s style to Heading 1.

Comment: you can probably just copy the text into a .html file and open it in Word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only resort to regex when I cannot achieve what I want with Words built in built in wildcard search.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Substituir(Optional ByVal this_tag As String = "h1", Optional ByVal this_replacement_style As String = "Heading 1")

    With ActiveDocument.Content

        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "(\<" & this_tag & "\>)(*)(\</" & this_tag & "\>)"   ' Default is "(<h1>)(*)(</h1>)"
            .Replacement.Text = "\2"
            .Format = True
            .Replacement.Style = this_replacement_style
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```